# SSL on postgresql FATAL ERROR

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I'm currently working on ubuntu 16.04. When I make ssl configurations for postgresql and then restart the service with this command:

`/etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

My database starts refusing the connections

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

How can I fix this?

Comment: what's your OS?.. try `psql -h localhost`

Comment: I fixed it but if you look at the file path it shows ubuntu as my OS